# Entity Framework Code First: One to one relationship not generating foreign key

Tags: ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-5

I have the following:

```
   public abstract class EntityBase
   {
      [Key]
      public int Id { get; set; }

      public DateTime? CreatedTime { get; set; }
      public DateTime? ModifiedTime { get; set; }
   }



public class AnalysisFile : EntityBase
   {
      public AnalysisFile()
      {
         DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
      }

      public string SourceFolder { get; set; }
      public string Filename { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
      public long FileSize { get; set; }
      public Document Document { get; set; }
   }

public class Document : EntityBase
   {
      public Document()
      {
         Publish = true;
      }

      public string Name { get; set; }
      public int AreaId { get; set; }
      public int SchoolId { get; set; }
      public int Year { get; set; }
      public long FileSize { get; set; }
      public AnalysisFile AnalysisFile { get; set; }
      public School School { get; set; }
      public Area Area { get; set; }
      public bool Publish { get; set; }
   }

     modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().HasRequired(x => x.AnalysisFile);
     modelBuilder.Entity<AnalysisFile>().HasOptional(x => x.Document);
```

My issue is that EF does not appear to create a foreign key for the relationship between AnalysisFile and Document, am I missing something here or is this the expected behavior?

I have also tried creating AnalysisFileId and DocumentId properties on both classes but when I do that they don't get populated with any ids.

Another question also: how can I ensure that Document has cascade-deletion against AnalysisFile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-to-one relationships with Entity Framework are [Shared Primary Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx). They don't have a separate foreign key column aside from the primary key because the primary key in `Document` is the foreign key to `AnalysisFile` at the same time. (You can see that when you inspect the relationship created in the database. It should relate the foreign key `Id` in `Document` with the primary key `Id` in `AnalysisFile`.)

You can enable cascading delete like so:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.AnalysisFile)
    .WithOptional(x => x.Document)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: I did wonder about the shared primary keys, thanks very much :-)